# Error in compiling a file with its own document class using MiKTeX 2.9.6643

Tags: latex-base, compilation-error

I had to re-install MiKTeX version (2.9.6643) after formatting my pc, but when I compiled the file of my dissertation I received these error messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\UseTextAccent ...up \@firstofone \let \@curr@enc 
                                                  \cf@encoding \@use@text@en...
l.3 \usepackage
               {makeidx}
? 
! Argument of \@font@info has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \usepackage
               {makeidx}
?
```

The file I am using has its own class (Thesis_André_en):

```
\documentclass[msc,wide,cover,hidelinks,nonomencl,bibkey]{Thesis_André_en} 
% hidelinks eliminates ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex
```

These error messages appear right after the document class.
The version I had installed in my pc was MiKteX 2.9.5105, which is the same one used in the university and I have never had any problems.

I solved these problems by re-installing the 2.9.5105 and deleting the 2.9.6643 one.
However, I'd like to know how I can solve this problem and still using the recent version of MiKTeX.

Obs.: the file Thesis_André_en is written in Portuguese and English.

Comment: Can you try to rename your class file without special characters? I.e. just `Thesis_Andre_en.cls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to only use ascii file names, but if you want to use the accented character then you may do

```
\documentclass[msc,wide,cover,hidelinks,nonomencl,bibkey]{\detokenize{Thesis_André_en}} 
% hidelinks eliminates ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex
```

We may possibly make this work automatically in a future release, but this form should work for old and future releases.